# CiviCRM under Drupal 7: the CiviCRM settings file (civicrm.settings.php) was not found in the expected location

Tags: drupal, civicrm.settings.php

After upgrading Drupal to 7.71 trying to follow strictly the instructions found at https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/update, the module CiviCRM was no longer visble.

Several error messages appeared in the browser at update.php:

```
Oops! - The CiviCRM settings file (civicrm.settings.php) was not found in the expected location (sites/default/civicrm.settings.php)
```

and

```
    Warning: include_once(sites/default/civicrm.settings.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in include_once() (line 200 of /usr/share/drupal/sites/all/modules/civicrm/drupal/civicrm.module).
    Warning: include_once(): Failed opening 'sites/default/civicrm.settings.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/usr/share/drupal/sites/all/modules/civicrm:/usr/share/drupal/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages:/usr/share/drupal/sites/all/modules/civicrm/vendor/tecnickcom:/usr/share/drupal/sites/all/modules/civicrm/vendor/phpseclib/phpseclib/phpseclib:/usr/share/drupal/sites/all/modules/civicrm/vendor/pear/pear_exception:/usr/share/drupal/sites/all/modules/civicrm/vendor/pear/auth_sasl:/usr/share/drupal/sites/all/modules/civicrm/vendor/pear/log:/usr/share/drupal/sites/all/modules/civicrm/vendor/pear/console_getopt:/usr/share/drupal/sites/all/modules/civicrm/vendor/pear/pear-core-minimal/src:/usr/share/drupal/sites/all/modules/civicrm/vendor/pear/mail:/usr/share/drupal/sites/all/modules/civicrm/vendor/pear/net_socket:/usr/share/drupal/sites/all/modules/civicrm/vendor/pear/net_smtp:/usr/share/drupal/sites/all/modules/civicrm/vendor/pear/validate_finance_creditcard:.:/usr/share/php') in include_once() (line 200 of /usr/share/drupal/sites/all/modules/civicrm/drupal/civicrm.module).
    Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in civicrm_menu_alter() (line 491 of /usr/share/drupal/sites/all/modules/civicrm/drupal/civicrm.module).
    Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in _block_rehash() (line 393 of /usr/share/drupal/modules/block/block.module).
```

I tried to re-install the module civicrm, and deleted the files located at `<drupal_root>/sites/all/modules/civicrm` but got nothing more than a white page.

Since I am new in Drupal and CiviCRM, I don't know how to proceed. I have a complete backup of the site before upgrading.

I managed to install `drush:7` with a lot of efforts, but issuing `drush status` gives me a bnch of warnings:

```
count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements     [warning]
Countable Table.php:789
count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements     [warning]
Countable Table.php:789
count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements     [warning]
Countable Table.php:789
count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements     [warning]
Countable Table.php:789
count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements     [warning]
Countable Table.php:789
count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements     [warning]
Countable Table.php:789
count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements     [warning]
Countable Table.php:789
count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements     [warning]
Countable Table.php:789
count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements     [warning]
Countable Table.php:789
count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements     [warning]
Countable Table.php:789
count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements     [warning]
Countable Table.php:789
count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements     [warning]
Countable Table.php:789
count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements     [warning]
Countable Table.php:789
count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements     [warning]
Countable Table.php:789
count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements     [warning]
Countable Table.php:789
count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements     [warning]
Countable Table.php:789
count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements     [warning]
Countable Table.php:789
count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements     [warning]
Countable Table.php:789
count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements     [warning]
Countable Table.php:789
count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements     [warning]
Countable Table.php:789
count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements     [warning]
Countable Table.php:789
count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements     [warning]
Countable Table.php:789
count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements     [warning]
Countable Table.php:789
count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements     [warning]
Countable Table.php:789
count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements     [warning]
Countable Table.php:789
count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements     [warning]
Countable Table.php:789
 Drupal version                  :  7.71                                        
 Site URI                        :  http://default                              
 Database driver                 :  mysql                                       
 Database hostname               :  localhost                                   
 Database port                   :                                              
 Database username               :  drupal                                      
 Database name                   :  drupal_civicrm                              
 Drupal bootstrap                :  Successful                                  
 Drupal user                     :                                              
 Default theme                   :  bartik                                      
 Administration theme            :  bartik                                      
 PHP executable                  :  /usr/bin/php                                
 PHP configuration               :  /etc/php/7.2/cli/php.ini                    
 PHP OS                          :  Linux                                       
 Drush script                    :  /home/pf/.composer/vendor/drush/drush/drush 
                                    .php                                        
 Drush version                   :  7.0.0                                       
 Drush temp directory            :  /tmp                                        
 Drush configuration             :                                              
 Drush alias files               :                                              
 Install profile                 :  minimal                                     
 Drupal root                     :  /usr/share/drupal                           
 Site path                       :  sites/default                               
 File directory path             :  sites/default/files                         
 Private file directory path     :  sites/default/files/private                 
 Temporary file directory path   :  /tmp
```

Any hint would be appreciated.

Comment: It sounds like as part of your drupal upgrade you maybe deleted something in sites/default? Also the drush error is because drush 7 is too old and isn't compatible with your version of php. You can install drush 8 and it will work with drupal 7.

Comment: I still have the content of the old site. Shoud I overwrite the new site with the content of old one? Partly? Completely?

Comment: Thank you for the hint: drush:7 was working before, but I will upgrade it to drush:8.

Comment: Overwriting might be the easiest. And you'd need to replace the database too.

Comment: Solved by extracting files manually from backup and by executing the mysql script included into thebackup  to rebuild the database.